# iterate through CSV and download filenames using FTP class

Tags: csv, ftp, loops

I am trying to read through CSV file with filenames that I would like to download from my ftp Server however I cant seem to get it to work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
  ftp = Net::FTP.new
  ftp.connect("myserver",21)
  ftp.login("myusername","mypassword")
  ftp.passive = false
  files = ftp.chdir('/')
  files = ftp.nlst("*.cfg")

  files=CSV.foreach("phonebook.csv") do |row|
  files=ftp.gettextfile(row,NIL)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I'm not sure if really had to do this but i converted my array to a string. This doesn't explain why i never get response from this forum, if someone can please tell me what I am doing Wrong?

```
    files=CSV.foreach("phonebook.csv") do |row|
    tempstr = row[0].to_s
    files = ftp.nlst(tempstr)
    files=ftp.getbinaryfile(tempstr)
```